# Flip Image around center

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

To flip an image around the center i am using this piece of code:

```
        // Calculate offset
        var offsetWidth:Number = image.contentWidth/2.0;
        var offsetHeight:Number =  image.contentHeight/2.0;
        // Perform flip
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.translate(-offsetWidth, -offsetHeight);
        if(direction=="HORIZONTAL"){
            matrix.scale(-1, 1);
        }else if(direction=="VERTICAL"){
            matrix.scale(1,-1)
        }
        matrix.translate(+offsetWidth, +offsetHeight);
        matrix.concat(image.transform.matrix);
        image.transform.matrix = matrix.clone();
```

which works fine.But my problem is when i try to get the BitmapData from the image like this:

```
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(image.width,image.height); 
        bitmapData.draw(image);
```

and use the bitmapData as source for another image,**no image is displayed.Broken image icon appears**.
Also i am rotating the image around center and using similar code as mentioned below and its working fine and i am able to copy the bitmapdata to another image..here's the code for reference:

```
   var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix(); 
   matrix.rotate(Math.PI/2); 
   matrix.tx = img.content.height; 
   var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.content.height, img.content.width);   
   bd.draw(img.content, matrix);
```

Please help regarding the same.

Comment: What exactly is your `image` object?

Comment: i am using an instance of mx.controls.Image.Image()...Also i am rotating the image also around center and using similar code as mentioned above and its working fine..here's is that for ur reference:var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.rotate(Math.PI/2);
   matrix.tx = img.content.height;
   var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(img.content.height, img.content.width);
   bd.draw(img.content, matrix);

Comment: it is better to update your question with this additional information :)

Comment: You know you can use Flex `Rotate` effect to rotate your object around right?

Comment: Could you look at your trace if any Sandbox violation error shows up? (your are not allowed to "draw" an image from a different sandbox)

Comment: I checked and there are no sandbox violations....after rotating i am able to draw the image again...it is happening only with flipping only..thats why posted the question as i am not able to debug the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is in the question.

In the second case you are using matrix

```
bd.draw(img.content, matrix);
```

Similarly do for the flip

```
bitmapData.draw(image, matrix);
```

EDIT:

Calculation of the translation for the matrix in flipping is not correct. Both the translation on X and Y are needed only when you flip horizontally and vertically.
Please find the code below in which it is working.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    [SWF(width="640", height="480")]

    public class FlipRotate extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="away3d.jpg")]
        private var Pic:Class;


        public function FlipRotate()
        {
            super();

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;


            var sourceImage:Bitmap;
            var targetImage:Bitmap;

            sourceImage = new Pic();

            //flip(sourceImage, "BOTH");
            flip(sourceImage, "VERTICAL");
            //flip(sourceImage, "BOTH");

            rotate(sourceImage, Math.PI/3);



            targetImage = new Bitmap();

            /* Get the current bounds of source image to calculate the dimenstion of new image
             Apply translation to bring the content outside into view in new image */
            var bounds:Rectangle = sourceImage.getBounds(this);
            var matrix:Matrix = sourceImage.transform.matrix;
            matrix.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y);

            /* Draw in new image applying translated matrix of source imgae */
            targetImage.bitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height);
            targetImage.bitmapData.draw(sourceImage, matrix);

            /* Add new image and postion at the center of stage */
            addChild(targetImage);
            targetImage.x = (stage.stageWidth-targetImage.width)/2;
            targetImage.y = (stage.stageHeight-targetImage.height)/2;

        }

        public function flip(image:Bitmap, direction:String):void{

            var matrix:Matrix = image.transform.matrix;

            if(direction=="HORIZONTAL"){
                matrix.scale(-1, 1);
                matrix.translate(image.width, 0);
            }else if(direction=="VERTICAL"){
                matrix.scale(1,-1);
                matrix.translate(0, image.height);
            }else if(direction == "BOTH"){
                matrix.scale(-1,-1);
                matrix.translate(image.width, image.height);
            }

            image.transform.matrix = matrix;

        }   

        public function rotate(image:Bitmap, angle:Number):void{

            var matrix:Matrix = image.transform.matrix;

            matrix.translate(-image.width/2, -image.height/2);
            matrix.rotate(angle); 
            matrix.translate(image.width/2, image.height/2);

            image.transform.matrix = matrix;

        }   


    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Let me experiment with this and find a solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer with working code. Please tell me if you need any clarification.